# How to open 2 workbench windows when start an RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I created a RCP product and want to open 2 workbench windows when I start it.

Each window has its own default perspective.

Comment: Do mean two different workbenches? Or one workbench with two windows?

Comment: Need 1 workbench with 2 windows and each window shows different perspective.